# Exceeded Maximum Allowed Simultaneous builds for your license

Tags: installanywhere

I am using InstallAnywhere 2017 and I see the below error after migrating the node locked license from one node to another.

It says I have to wait for 12 hours and I have waited for so long. But no luck.

Can anyone help with this.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraaaq.ae(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraad8.bw(Unknown Source)
at InstallAnywhere.ae(Unknown Source)
at InstallAnywhere.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
Simultaneous Build Manager: Error !!!
Reason=Exceeded Maximum Allowed Simultaneous builds for your license.
Remedy=Please try building after one of your existing build processes complete.
Note=You could also face this issue if you have cancelled the builds using Ctrl+C.In this case, your token is locked out and it will be automatically released within 12 hours.
logNonCEIPDataForSales(): NoRouteToHostException: Update Server is not available.
```

As mentioned here, I have waited for 12 hours. But, still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try uninstalling InstallAnywhere 2017 completely.
2. You will see hidden directory with name InstallAnywhere under user. Back up 'Preferences' folder under 170, 180 or 190 in the user profile (on Windows) or the user's home directory (on Linux). Clear the 170,180 or 190 folder.
3. Restart machine and Reinstall IA. It should fix the issue.